# 'ContinueWith' can be called with these arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-oauth

Using the OAuthDesktopApp example posted here: https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows , and converted to vb.net, there is a line of code which reads:

```
Dim responseTask As Task = responseOutput.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ContinueWith(Sub(task)
                                                                               responseOutput.Close()
                                                                               http.Stop()
                                                             Console.WriteLine("HTTP server stopped.")
                                                                               End Sub)
```

Which works fine in a WPF application when run using the dot net framework version 4.6.1.  However, the same code in a Windows Forms application using the same dot net framework version results in the following exception being thrown at run time:

> Failed at ( ResolveOverloadedCall )
> Overload resolution failed because no Public 'ContinueWith' can be called with these arguments:
> 'Public Function ContinueWith(continuationAction As System.Action`1[[System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Task(Of VoidTaskResult))) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task':
> Argument matching parameter 'continuationAction' cannot convert from 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of Object)' to 'Action(Of Task(Of VoidTaskResult))'.
> 'Public Function ContinueWith(Of TNewResult)(continuationFunction As Func(Of Task(Of VoidTaskResult),TNewResult)) As Task(Of TNewResult)':
> Type argument inference fails for argument matching parameter 'continuationFunction'.
> 'Public Function ContinueWith(Of TResult)(continuationFunction As Func(Of Task,TResult)) As Task(Of TResult)':
> Type argument inference fails for argument matching parameter 'continuationFunction'.
> 'Public Function ContinueWith(continuationAction As System.Action(Of Task)) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task':
> Argument matching parameter 'continuationAction' cannot convert from 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of Object)' to 'Action(Of Task)'.

I've tried changing the version of the dot net framework, and searching stackoverflow for clues - but to no success.

For reference the original c code in the example is:

```
Task responseTask = responseOutput.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ContinueWith((task) => 
        {
            responseOutput.Close();
            http.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("HTTP server stopped.");
        });
```

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using `await` ?

Comment: You can `Dim responseTask = await responseOutput.WriteAsync(...)` and move the clean-up code after. Or return the Task, as a Function.

Comment: The samples you link to are 5 years old and contain some critical bugs in the console sample: `async void` should *only* be used in event handlers. `async void` methods can't be awaited, they're essentially fire-and-forget. Instead of `async void doAsync` the sample methods should be `async Task doAsync`.

Comment: This is a very old repo you are following which has not seen any love for many a year, and it has some major issues.   Google is trying to updated it. I have pinged someone who may be able to help you.  You will have to wait and see if you get a response.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  Thanks esp. to Panagiotis and Jimi - your suggestion worked great.  Re the old repo, understood, but that is all that I could find that worked under WPF - it just didn't work under Windows Forms (which is what I needed).  Again, thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments

```
Dim response = Await responseOutput.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
```

(And add error handling)